# JS function call won't work in Chrome and Opera (JS + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, opera

I can't seem to get the following functionality to work under **Chrome and Opera** (latest versions on Windows XP).
The code is:

```
$.getScript('/js/modules/'+module+'.js', function() {
    setTimeout('window.'+module+'_init()', 800);
});
```

Everything seems to work fine, the script loads, init function exists (a few debug alerts within that setTimeout statement verified that type of **"window.module_init"** really is a ***function***) but the function just won't run.

I tried putting a simple alert at the beginning of that init function, leave ONLY an alert there - nothing helped.

I must say I'm quite puzzled by this, as this works just fine under Firefox and MSIE.

FYI, the init function in that external js file simply looks like this:

```
function notifications_init() {
    alert('test');
}
```

"**notifications**" is the value of my "module" variable above

Any advice is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The console does not give any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(window[module+'_init'], 800);
```

Comment: that solved it, thanx... one question however - should I be using window as an array instead of using "window.variable" to access a variable defined in this fashion: var abc = 1

Comment: You aren't using window as an array, its just a different notation...http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#squarebracket

Answer (score 0):

How about `setTimeout('window.'+module+'_init', 800);`, without the braces?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested what you are explaining here and it worked great here. I am guessing that the external js file that you are loading using `$.getScript` contains errors.

Could you comment everything inside that file except for the `notifications_init()` you have in your question?

This is what I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('start');
        var module = 'test';
        $.getScript('/Scripts/' + module + '.js', function () {
            alert('script was loaded and executed');
            setTimeout('window.' + module + '_init()', 800);
        });
        alert('finish');
    });
</script>
```

And test.js contains only this:

```
function test_init() {
    alert('test function');
}
```